# Representation theory question + SU(n)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Would you please help me in how to solve these questions :

A- Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group  $G$.Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be class function of $G$ and $H$ respectively. Prove that 
$$Ind^{G}_{H} (\beta . Res^{G}_{H})= \alpha .Ind^{G}_{H}(\beta) $$

---

B- Show that

1.Each element in $SU(n)$ conjugate to a diagonal matrix.

1. Every character of $SU(n)$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to subgroup $T$ consisting of all diagonal matrices whose diagonal coefficients have absolute value 1.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the notation please?

Comment: Ind is the induced representation
Res is the restricted representation

Comment: I think it means the image of Ind:R(H)->R(G)is an ideal of the ring R(G)... Is that right or not? .. if yes, how can I show that?? Also if not , please help me to solve it :)

Comment: Dear Martin, I think there is an $\alpha$ missing on the left side of your formula.  Also, your two questions are completely unrelated (as far as I can tell), so I would suggest asking them separately.